# Stochastic Integration: How to show that with a continuous martingale as integrator a trading strategy is converging in probability to a limit of sums

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am given a continuous martingale $M_t$ with $M_0 = 0$ and a trading strategy $H$ (a left-continuous stochastic process who is here bounded also). 
I have a sequence of partitions $t_i$ $\in \Pi^n$ $\in [0,T]$(who converges towards $0$ in the limit).

The statement I have to proof is:

For any sequence $ (\Pi^n)_{n \in N} $ it holds :

$\mathcal{P}\left[ \int_0^t H_s d M_s = lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t_i \in \Pi^n} H_{t_i} ( M_{t_{i+1} \land t} - M_{t_i \land t})\right] = 1 ,t \in [0,T]$

I can (and probably should) make use of the following statement:

If $lim_{n \to \infty}H^n \to 0 (pointwise)$ then it holds that $\mathcal{P}\left[ lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{t \in [0,T]} |(H^n \bullet M )_t| = 0\right] = 1$

($X \bullet Y$) stands for the Itô-integral.

I am thinking about this for almost a week and do not really have any idea how to approach this proof. 
I do not know how the additional 'statement to use' helps (I guess I should somewhere arrive where I can either (or both) deduct that my statement to proof is smaller than a sum of supremas and/or that my H is also pontwise converging to 0 ).
I assume it has to because I would directly conclude that it follows directly by the boundedness and continiuty of H and M, but there has to be some steps inbetween. A steering in the right direction would be really helpful (and I would be thankful for it).

Edit:
With the hint of Brian, define a sequence of trading strategies given by
$H_t^n=H_t−H_{max \left[ t_i∈Π^n∣t_i≤t\right]  } $ and lets compute 
$H^n \bullet M = lim \sum H_{t_i}^n (M_{t_{i+1} \land t} - M_{t_i \land t})$
= $lim \sum (H_t−H_{max \left[ t_j∈Π^n∣t_j≤t_i\right] ) } ((M_{t_{i+1} \land t} - M_{t_i \land t})$

If we take this in probability we should arrive (somehow) at
$\mathcal{P}\left[ \int_0^t H_s d M_s = lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t_i \in \Pi^n} H_{t_i} ( M_{t_{i+1} \land t} - M_{t_i \land t})\right] = 1$

I do not know how to arrive at this statement from the calculation above.
Another hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Define a sequence of trading strategies given by
$$H^n_t = H_t - H_{\max\{t_i\in \Pi^n \mid t_i \leq t\}}$$
What is $H^n\bullet M$ for this sequence?

Comment: Thank you for the hint Brian, I am still lost a bit.

Comment: First, a small correction on my part.  My $H^n_t$ wasn't left-continuous, so to correct this, $\max\{t_i \in \Pi^n \mid t_i \leq t\}$ should have been $\max\{t_i \in \Pi^n \mid t_i < t\}$.  Second, what is your working definition of the Ito integral: does it require evenly spaced partitions or just any sequence of partitions whose mesh goes to zero? As you have seemingly defined it, the proof is much simpler:  All you have to do is note that 
$$\Pi^n_t = (\Pi^n \cup \{t\}) \setminus (t, T]$$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$ whose mesh goes to zero.